# builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def find_index(string):
'''(str) -> int
Return the index of the AND or OR symbol which is most outside
of the input string.
REQ: the first and last elements of the string must be "(" and
")" respectively.
>>> find_index("((-x+y)*-(-y+x))")
7
>>> find_index("(-x+y)")
3
'''
s = string[1:-1]
for i in range(len(s)):
    left = s.count(L_BRACKET, 0, i)
    right = s.count(R_BRACKET, 0, i)
    if left - right == 0 and s[i] in AND + OR:
        index = i + 1
return index
```

Here is a function I wrote to find the symbol outside most of the input string,
but when i test it like 
find_index("(x)"), it should return None, but python gives me an error 
 builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment
how should i imprve my code, i'm using python 3

Comment: You are never entering your `with` block, so when you get to `return index` it has never been assigned to thus the error. Try using a default value, maybe `index = None` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Error message is very clear, there is no `index` to be return.

Try this:

```
index = 0
s = string[1:-1]
for i in range(len(s)):
    left = s.count(L_BRACKET, 0, i)
    right = s.count(R_BRACKET, 0, i)
    if left - right == 0 and s[i] in AND + OR:
        index = i + 1
return index
```